# How to set up tables correctly in MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, office365

**Context**

I work for a metal building screw manufacturer we paint and bag them. Blanks are the parts we start with. On the following commas separate part numbers and the corresponding part and back slash separate # and parts from other parts all the parts in a row come from same blank.  The 100,250 and CTN on the same row are the same color but are bagged 100, 250 or just boxed.

> Blank #,Blank Part-Color-powder #,powder part-bagged 100#,bagged 100
>   part-bagged 250#, bagged 250 part-CTN#,CTN part

I have a price line # that is the same per type of screw no matter how they are processed.  This is how 1 line looks.  I have over 500 lines BTW.

> 10110/67543,12B100DMCOZ/56471,12B100DMCOPS
>   BN03/BN03/09879,12B100DMC0PS BN03-100/65987,12B100DMC0PS
>   BN03-250/12121,12B100DMC0PS BN03-CTN

Blanks make painted item, painted item then there are 3 Choices  bagged 100,250, CTN or a mix of them.

I am just starting out with Access coming from using Excel I can use very very little VBA learning it still.  This is with MS  Office 365.

**Problem**

What is the best way to separate the table or even if I should? I will need to be able to add parts in the Future.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a powerful import tool that allows you to import data and to specify things like separators (comma, pipe, whatever-you-say-it-is) and whether the data comes with headers, etc. You can also save the import rules so that you can use this specification to import the data again down the road, or even to link the text-file in dynamically so that it's treated as a table from within your database. [starting point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifRCG.png)

Comment: Thanks for the information but, your not understanding my problem.  I might not have stated it plainly enough. right now its all 1 big table.  I just don't know if or how far I should separate it.  Should I separate it by size of screw and type, just type, should I separate by type, size, bagged 100, bagged 250, and CTN Part.  Is a lot of very small tables better than larger ones. I could separate it where each table has about 30 rows and 5 or six columns counting the Lookup columns, but there would be about 20 tables with the screws in them and around 10 Look up tables.